# Trouble with indentation of child elements in SwiftUI Picker

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I'm currently working on a SwiftUI (for macOS) project and have encountered an issue with the indentation of child elements within a Picker. I have a Picker with a list of items, where each item can have child items. The problem is that the child items are not being indented correctly within the picker.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
struct NewList: Hashable, Identifiable {
    var id: UUID = UUID()
    
    static func == (lhs: NewList, rhs: NewList) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    
    public func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        return hasher.combine(id)
    }
    
    var listName: String
    var listItems: [NewList]?
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let words = [
        NewList(listName: "First", listItems: []),
        NewList(listName: "Second", listItems: []),
        NewList(listName: "Third", listItems: [
            NewList(listName: "XX", listItems: []),
            NewList(listName: "YY", listItems: [])
        ]),
        NewList(listName: "Four", listItems: []),
        NewList(listName: "Five", listItems: [
            NewList(listName: "AA", listItems: []),
            NewList(listName: "BB", listItems: [])
        ]),
        NewList(listName: "Six", listItems: []),
    ]
    
    @State var selectedWord: NewList?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Selected Item: \(selectedWord?.listName ?? "")")
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
            
            Form {
                Picker("Word:", selection: $selectedWord) {
                    ForEach (words) { word in
                        Text (word.listName)
                            .tag(word)
                        if let listItems = word.listItems, !listItems.isEmpty {
                            ForEach(listItems) { newWord in
                                Text (newWord.listName).padding(.leading)
                                    .tag(newWord)
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .padding(40)
    }
}
```

The indentation seems to be working fine for the top-level items, but when it comes to the child items, they are not indented as expected. I've tried using .padding(.leading) for the child items, but it doesn't seem to have the desired effect.

I want the child items to be visually distinct and properly indented under their parent items in the Picker. Has anyone else encountered a similar issue or can provide guidance on how to achieve proper indentation for child elements within a Picker in SwiftUI?

[image: View Image]

Thanks to a helpful suggestion from the community, I've implemented a solution that add spaces in-front of String to be displayed in Text.

Now, my question is how can I extend this solution to include an icon for each PickerItem? I would like each PickerItem to have an associated icon, like the following:

```
HStack {
    Image(systemName: "xmark")
    Text(item.listName)
}
```

Is there a way to seamlessly integrate this spacing in front of the icon?

Comment: I don't think you can control indentation. I would just add some spaces to the start of each string.

Comment: I think customising the presentation of the elements of a Picker is quite limited.
 You could `fake` it using, `Text ("    " + newWord.listName)`.
 Note, your tags should be of the form, `.tag(word as NewList?)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments you can't much with Text or other components inside a Picker so you need to change the input instead.

One way is to have a custom init for `Text` that will indent the given text for you

```
extension Text {
    init<S>(_ text: S, indentation: Int) where S : StringProtocol {
        var prefix: String = ""
        if indentation > 0 {
            prefix = String(repeating: " ", count: indentation)
        }

        self.init(prefix.appending(text))
    }
}
```

And then replace your current Text in the Picker with this

```
Form {
    Picker("Word:", selection: $selectedWord) {
        ForEach (words) { word in
            Text(word.listName).tag(word)
            ForEach(word.listItems) { newWord in
                Text(newWord.listName, indentation: 4).tag(newWord)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I simplified your code somewhat by making `listItems` non optional in `NewList`

Comment: This looks good. In this fix we are adding space infront of the actual string. But I also need an icon for the PickerItem like this.

```
                                HStack {
                                    Image(systemName: "xmark")
                                        .padding(.leading, 30)
                                    Text(newWord.listName)
                                }
                                .tag(newWord)
```

Comment: That's not related to the question you asked.